# CATransition Push transition replacing content early

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-animation, caanimation

I have a simple animation setup in a Mac App where a page control swaps out some views. I am very close to getting the paging-like animation I want, but there is a slight problem. The paging works and the new page animates into place correctly, but the new page also replaces the initial page *before* the animation. I wish to ultimately have the view that is being pushed out remain the same instead of changing to the new page early. [Here is a video showing the problem](http://f.cl.ly/items/0w3x2h2g203W1b3V2W1m/SO.mov), slowed down to a 3 second animation duration.  Here is the code:

```
UASourceView *previousSourceView = [self.sourceViewContainer.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
NSInteger previousIndex = [self.sourceViews indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:previousSourceView];

CATransition *pushTransition = [CATransition animation];
[pushTransition setType:kCATransitionPush];
[pushTransition setSubtype:(previousIndex < index) ? kCATransitionFromRight : kCATransitionFromLeft];
[pushTransition setDuration:PANEL_PAGE_SWIPE_ANIMATION_DURATION];
[pushTransition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[pushTransition setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];

[CATransaction begin];
[self.sourceViewContainer replaceSubview:previousSourceView with:sourceView];
[CATransaction commit];

[sourceView.layer addAnimation:pushTransition forKey:@"push"];
```

There is a fixed container view `self.sourceViewContainer` that gets a new subview replaced on every animation. The problem, as seen above is that the `previousSourceView` gets replaced immediately by the `sourceView` **and** gets pushed in as well. Please help me stop the immediate replacement. Where am I going wrong?

*Note, `iOS` tag is added because this code is platform independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved similar issues using [CAAnimationBlocks](https://github.com/trojanfoe/CAAnimationBlocks) (this is my fork of the [original](https://github.com/xissburg/CAAnimationBlocks), which the author has moved in a direction I didn't much care for).

The idea is to set `removedOnCompletion` to `NO` and `fillMode` to `kCAFillModeForwards` and perform the actual switch (without animation) in the completion block.  This has been tested under OSX only (you might need a different solution for iOS, which already supports completion blocks).

Here's an example usage from my code, which moves a piece on a chess board, and back again:

```
CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
moveAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:[self _pointForSquare:move.from()]];
moveAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:[self _pointForSquare:move.to()]];
moveAnimation.duration = _animateSpeed / 1000.0;
moveAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
moveAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
moveAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
moveAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
moveAnimation.completion = ^(BOOL finished)
{
    [pieceLayer removeAnimationForKey:@"movePiece"];
    [self _setPieceLayer:pieceLayer toPiece:piece];
    [pieceLayer setNeedsDisplay];
};

[pieceLayer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey:@"movePiece"];
```